# Finding a regx expression in pyspark?

Tags: python, regex, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
I have a column in pyspark dataframe which contain values separated by ; 

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|name                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|tppid=dfc36cc18bba07ae2419a1501534aec6fdcc22e0dcefed4f58c48b0169f203f6;xmaslist=no|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So, in this column any number of key value pair can come if i use this

```
df.withColumn('test', regexp_extract(col('name'), '(?<=tppid=)(.*?);', 1)).show(1,False)
```

i can extract the tppid but when tppid comes as last key-value pair in a row it not able to extract, I want a regx which can extract the value of a key where ever the location of it in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a negated character class `[^;]` to match any char but `;`:

```
tppid=([^;]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f8H2QS/1)

Since the third argument to `regexp_extract` is `1` (accessing Group 1 contents),  you may discard the lookbehind construct and use `tppid=` as part of the consuming pattern.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the Wiktor Stribiżew's answer, you can use anchors. `$` is denoting the end of the string.

```
tppid=\w+(?=;|\s|$)
```

Also [this](https://regex101.com/r/jEqPfe/1) regex extract for you only the values without the `tppid=` part:

```
(?<=tppid=)\w+(?=;|\s|$)
```

Comment: However, these patterns won't work with OP current code.